# Proof that PCA is equivalent to MDS when using Euclidean distances

Tags: linear-algebra, principal-component-analysis

As I was watching a video explaining how MDS works, the narrator mentioned that PCA is equivalent to MDS when Euclidean distances are used. I got confused as to how that's the case.

My guess is that it has to do with SVD but I don't know how to properly prove it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to explain your initialisms. PCA is principal component analysis, SVD is singular value decomposition, and MDS is probably multidimensional scaling

Comment: Assuming that I'm right, you should find [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/14002/128205) to be helpful